# Logitech LCD SDk (C++)

Tags: c++, image, sdk, progress-bar, logitech

I have a problem with the Logitech LCD SDK. Everything works but 2 simple things don't work. First I can't get the progressbar to work. I update every second the value of the progressbar and i update the screen. Nothing happend. I have tested the values from 0 to 100 and from 0 to 1 with no differents.

Second problem is the images in VS2012. I can't load images in a c++ Dll.
The code below is my Logitech class with all the data for the screen.
The full source can be found at [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/jimmyD/musicbee-logitech-applet/src).

I hope somebody can help me with it?

EDIT: The problem lies in the progressbar. The code for all the rest works eg. It draws everything on the logitech LCD screen, even the progressbar, times, ... But the real problem lies in the progressbar's progress. This meens the bar background draws perfect, but the progressbar doesnt move, it seems to have fixed at around 15% progress. Normaly the progress must be linked at the time of the music eg if the musicfile is 3 minutes that means that 180 seconds must transend as 100% progress. But this doesnt work!

```
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Logitech File
// C++ Source - Logitech.cpp - version 2012 v1.0
//-----------------------------------------------------------------

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Include Files
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Logitech.h"

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Logitech methods
//-----------------------------------------------------------------

//This LogitechObject is a instance of the Logitech class for using in the thread
Logitech * Logitech::LogitechObject;

Logitech::Logitech():   stopthread(false), firstTime(true), position(0), duration(0)
{
    LogitechObject = this;
}

Logitech::~Logitech()
{
    stopthread = true;
    this->state = StatePlay::Undefined;
    timerThread.detach();
}

bool Logitech::getFirstTime()
{
    return firstTime;
}

//Initialise Logitech LCD
BOOL Logitech::OnInitDialog()
{
    HRESULT hRes = m_lcd.Initialize(_T("MusicBee"), LG_DUAL_MODE, FALSE, TRUE);

    if (hRes != S_OK)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    //Create home screen Logitech Color LCD
    if(m_lcd.IsDeviceAvailable(LG_COLOR))
    {
        m_lcd.ModifyDisplay(LG_COLOR);
        logo = m_lcd.AddText(LG_STATIC_TEXT, LG_BIG, DT_CENTER, LGLCD_BW_BMP_WIDTH);
        m_lcd.SetOrigin(logo, 0, 50);
        m_lcd.SetText(logo, _T("MusicBee"));
        m_lcd.Update();
    }

    //Create home screen Logitech Monochrome LCD
    else if(m_lcd.IsDeviceAvailable(LG_MONOCHROME))
    {
        m_lcd.ModifyDisplay(LG_MONOCHROME);
        logo = m_lcd.AddText(LG_STATIC_TEXT, LG_BIG, DT_CENTER, LGLCD_BW_BMP_WIDTH);
        m_lcd.SetOrigin(logo, 0, 5);
        m_lcd.SetText(logo, _T("MusicBee"));
        m_lcd.Update();
    }

    //Start thread
    timerThread = thread(&Logitech::startThread);

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

//Create playing screen for Logitech Monochrome LCD
VOID Logitech::createMonochrome()
{
    m_lcd.RemovePage(0);
    m_lcd.AddNewPage();
    m_lcd.ShowPage(0);

    if (logo != 0)
    {
        delete logo;
        logo = 0;
    }

    artist = m_lcd.AddText(LG_SCROLLING_TEXT, LG_MEDIUM, DT_CENTER, LGLCD_BW_BMP_WIDTH);
    m_lcd.SetOrigin(artist, 0, 0);

    title = m_lcd.AddText(LG_SCROLLING_TEXT, LG_MEDIUM, DT_CENTER, LGLCD_BW_BMP_WIDTH);
    m_lcd.SetOrigin(title, 0, 13);

    progressbar = m_lcd.AddProgressBar(LG_FILLED);
    m_lcd.SetProgressBarSize(progressbar, 136, 5);
    m_lcd.SetOrigin(progressbar, 12, 38);

    time = m_lcd.AddText(LG_STATIC_TEXT, LG_SMALL, DT_LEFT, 80);
    m_lcd.SetOrigin(time, 12, 29);

    time1 = m_lcd.AddText(LG_STATIC_TEXT, LG_SMALL, DT_LEFT, 80);
    m_lcd.SetOrigin(time1, 125, 29);

    /*  playIcon = static_cast<HICON>(LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG2), IMAGE_BITMAP, 16, 16, LR_MONOCHROME));
    playIconHandle = m_lcd.AddIcon(playIcon, 16, 16);
    m_lcd.SetOrigin(playIconHandle, 2, 29);*/

    firstTime = false;
    changeArtistTitle(this->artistString, this->albumString, this->titleString, this->durationString, this->position);
}

//Create playing screen for Logitech Color LCD
VOID Logitech::createColor()
{
    m_lcd.RemovePage(0);
    m_lcd.AddNewPage();
    m_lcd.ShowPage(0);

    if (logo != 0)
    {
        delete logo;
        logo = 0;
    }

    artist = m_lcd.AddText(LG_SCROLLING_TEXT, LG_MEDIUM, DT_CENTER, 320);
    m_lcd.SetOrigin(artist, 5, 5);

    album = m_lcd.AddText(LG_SCROLLING_TEXT, LG_MEDIUM, DT_CENTER, 320);
    m_lcd.SetOrigin(album, 5, 30);

    title = m_lcd.AddText(LG_SCROLLING_TEXT, LG_MEDIUM, DT_CENTER, 320);
    m_lcd.SetOrigin(title, 5, 55);

    time = m_lcd.AddText(LG_STATIC_TEXT, LG_SMALL, DT_LEFT, 80);
    m_lcd.SetOrigin(time, 5, 80);

    time1 = m_lcd.AddText(LG_STATIC_TEXT, LG_SMALL, DT_LEFT, 80);
    m_lcd.SetOrigin(time1, 275, 80);

    progressbar = m_lcd.AddProgressBar(LG_DOT_CURSOR);//320×240 pixel color screen
    m_lcd.SetProgressBarSize(progressbar, 310, 15);
    m_lcd.SetOrigin(progressbar, 5, 100);

    time1 = m_lcd.AddText(LG_STATIC_TEXT, LG_SMALL, DT_LEFT, 80);
    m_lcd.SetOrigin(time1, 275, 80);

    /*playIcon = static_cast<HICON>(LoadImage(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_COLOR));
    playIconHandle = m_lcd.AddIcon(playIcon, 16, 16);
    m_lcd.SetOrigin(playIconHandle, 5, 29);*/

    firstTime = false;
    changeArtistTitle(this->artistString, this->albumString, this->titleString, this->durationString, this->position);
}

void Logitech::startThread()
{
    while(!LogitechObject->stopthread)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds(500) );

        if(!LogitechObject->stopthread && LogitechObject->progressbar != NULL)
        {
            //Update progressbar and position time on the screen after 1 second of music.
            if(LogitechObject->state == StatePlay::Playing)
            {
                this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds(500) );
                LogitechObject->position++;

                LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetProgressBarPosition(LogitechObject->progressbar, static_cast<FLOAT>(((float)LogitechObject->position / LogitechObject->duration)*100));
                LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetText(LogitechObject->time, LogitechObject->getPositionString().c_str());
            }

            //If music stopped then the progressbar and time must stop immediately
            else if(LogitechObject->state == StatePlay::Stopped)
            {
                LogitechObject->position = 0;
                LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetProgressBarPosition(LogitechObject->progressbar, 0);
                LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetText(LogitechObject->time, LogitechObject->getPositionString().c_str());
            }

            LogitechObject->m_lcd.Update();
        }
    }
}

void Logitech::changeArtistTitle(wstring artistStr, wstring albumStr, wstring titleStr, wstring duration, int position)
{
    this->artistString = artistStr;
    this->albumString = albumStr;
    this->titleString = titleStr;
    this->durationString = duration;
    this->position = position;
    this->duration = getDuration(duration);

    if(!firstTime)
    {
        if(m_lcd.IsDeviceAvailable(LG_COLOR))
        {
            m_lcd.SetText(album, albumStr.c_str());
        }


        m_lcd.SetText(artist, artistStr.c_str());
        m_lcd.SetText(title, titleStr.c_str());
        m_lcd.SetText(time, getPositionString().c_str());

        string s( duration.begin(), duration.end() );

        if(s.size() < 5)
        {
            s = "0" + s;
        }

        wstring ws( s.begin(), s.end() );

        m_lcd.SetText(time1, ws.c_str());
        ws.clear();

        ///*playIcon = static_cast<HICON>(LoadImage(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_COLOR));
        //playIconHandle = m_lcd.AddIcon(playIcon, 16, 16);
        //m_lcd.SetOrigin(playIconHandle, 5, 29);*/

        m_lcd.Update();
        artistStr.clear();
        albumStr.clear();
        titleStr.clear();
        duration.clear();
    }
}

//Set current playing position
void Logitech::setPosition(int pos)
{
    this->position = pos/1000;
    m_lcd.SetText(time, getPositionString().c_str());
    m_lcd.Update();
}

//Change play state of the current playing song
void Logitech::changeState(StatePlay state)
{
    this->state = state;

    if(state == StatePlay::Playing && firstTime)
    {
        if(m_lcd.IsDeviceAvailable(LG_COLOR))
        {
            createColor();
        }

        else if(m_lcd.IsDeviceAvailable(LG_MONOCHROME))
        {
            createMonochrome();
        }
    }
}

//Gets the music duration
int Logitech::getDuration(wstring duration)
{
    string s( duration.begin(), duration.end() );

    int position = s.find(":");
    string minutes = s.substr(0, s.size() -position);
    string seconds = s.substr(position);
    int minutesInt = atoi(minutes.c_str());
    int secondsInt = atoi(seconds.c_str());

    return (minutesInt *60) + secondsInt;
}

//Change current position in string
wstring Logitech::getPositionString()
{
    string minutes = to_string((int)position /60);
    string seconds = to_string((int)position%60);

    if(minutes.size() < 2)
    {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }

    if(seconds.size() < 2)
    {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }

    string time = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    return wstring( time.begin(), time.end() );
}
```

Comment: What you've posted doesn't give anyone much to go on as far as helping you.  You say "everything works but 2 simple things don't work" but it isn't clear what "everything" it is that works.  Do you get anything to print on the display at all?  Does your progress bar print the first time but not subsequent times?  You need to do a little better job of explaining the problem if you want help on it.

Comment: better explained my problem (see EDIT in first post)

Comment: You have several places in your code like `if(object->state == 7)`, but no explanation of what the heck `7` means.  Add an enum that describes the valid states in English and make `object->state` be that enum type.  Then, either rename `object` to something meaningful, or in comments, describe what the heck the `object` is.  Edit the code in your post accordingly, and I'll take another look.  And, if it's not clear by the enum names, I'm curious in `Logitech::startThread()` why `object->state==3` has an extra half-second sleep, while `object->state==7` does not.  And in general, add comments.

Comment: Changed ints to enums and added more comments :). (see Code in first post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you go trying to figure out what's wrong with your code, you should verify that the SDK operates as you expect it to.

Please add this code at the top of your `Logitech::startThread()` and let me know what happens:

```
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetText(LogitechObject->time, "ProgressBar TEST SEQUENCE");
this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds(2000) );
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetText(LogitechObject->time, "ProgressBar TEST 0%");
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetProgressBarPosition(LogitechObject->progressbar, 0);
this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds(2000) );
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetText(LogitechObject->time, "ProgressBar TEST 10%");
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetProgressBarPosition(LogitechObject->progressbar, 10);
this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds(2000) );
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetText(LogitechObject->time, "ProgressBar TEST 20%");
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetProgressBarPosition(LogitechObject->progressbar, 20);
this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds(2000) );
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetText(LogitechObject->time, "ProgressBar TEST 30%");
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetProgressBarPosition(LogitechObject->progressbar, 30);
this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds(2000) );
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetText(LogitechObject->time, "ProgressBar TEST 40%");
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetProgressBarPosition(LogitechObject->progressbar, 40);
this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds(2000) );
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetText(LogitechObject->time, "ProgressBar TEST 50%");
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetProgressBarPosition(LogitechObject->progressbar, 50);
this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds(2000) );
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetText(LogitechObject->time, "ProgressBar TEST 60%");
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetProgressBarPosition(LogitechObject->progressbar, 60);
this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds(2000) );
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetText(LogitechObject->time, "ProgressBar TEST 70%");
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetProgressBarPosition(LogitechObject->progressbar, 70);
this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds(2000) );
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetText(LogitechObject->time, "ProgressBar TEST 80%");
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetProgressBarPosition(LogitechObject->progressbar, 80);
this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds(2000) );
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetText(LogitechObject->time, "ProgressBar TEST 90%");
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetProgressBarPosition(LogitechObject->progressbar, 90);
this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds(2000) );
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetText(LogitechObject->time, "ProgressBar TEST 100%");
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetProgressBarPosition(LogitechObject->progressbar, 100);
this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds(2000) );
LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetText(LogitechObject->time, "ProgressBar TEST COMPLETE");
this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds(2000) );
```

Ideally it would set the progress bar to each percentage for two seconds at a time, allowing you to verify that the progress bar operates as you expect it to.  If this doesn't work, there's not much point in trying to figure out what's wrong with your own code; either somethings's wrong with the SDK or else your understanding of its control parameters does not match the SDK's requirements.

Let me know your results.

Comment: Tnx for your help. We have found the problem. Thanks to your testcode we have tracked the problem down to the file from the Logitech sdk. problem is now solved.

Comment: @TestJef - Great!  So what was the actual problem?

Comment: Some code of the SetProgressBarPosition in the Logitech SDK was in comment. We have uncommented that code and now it works.

Comment: @TestJef - Glad it works for you now.  If my suggestions were helpful, please select and/or upvote my answer.

Comment: I need 15 reputation to upvote it. If I get 15 reputation I will upvote it. Tnx a lot.